# Remove landing page of Jboss 7

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I have deployed my application in jboss 7. It is in the url www.myappurl.com/appname/.
But if I go to www.myappurl.com/index.html I see Jboss's landing page that says "Welcome to JBoss AS 7".

How Can I remove that page?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically you have to set to false the **enable-welcome-root** property of the Virtual Server that you are using and specify into the **jboss-web.xml** that the application is bound into the Root Web Context ("/").
See this [tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-web-server/how-to-deploy-a-web-application-on-the-root-context-on-jboss-as-7). 
Hope it helps. Francesco

Answer (score 0):

you have to deploy an application that has **Context Path** set to **/**

**UPDATE**

Looking some resources on the internet such as this http://stephou.wordpress.com/2012/05/05/how-to-deploy-to-jboss-as7-default-root-context/ say that you have to modify first your standalone.xml else it will raise an exception.

From personal experience i just set the Context Path of my webapp to / (root) and it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

you can remove these lines in the standalone.xml:

```
<location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>

<handlers>
    <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
</handlers>
```